# PHP unsetting all variables with 'tmp' at the front

Tags: php, loops, foreach, session-variables

I'm simply looking to loop through all current session variables and if the session variable name begins with 'tmp' then I want to unset the variable.

I would do it as follows:

```
foreach($session as $sv){
    if(substr($sv,0,3)=='tmp'){
        unset($sv);
    }
}
```

Just not sure how to get all the current session variables into an array to start with.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thanks for all the quick responses. I feel like a bit of an idiot now for not realising that $_SESSION was an array itself. Got there now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's the problem with

```
foreach (array_keys($_SESSION) as $key) {
    if (substr($key,0,3) == 'tmp') {
        unset($_SESSION[$key]);
    }
}
```

?

Answer (score 1):

`$_SESSION` holds every session variable

```
foreach(array_keys($_SESSION) as $sv){
    if(substr($sv, 0, 3) === 'tmp'){
        unset($_SESSION[$sv]);
    }
}
```

is correct

Comment: You're checking the session variable's value for `tmp*` instead of the name.

Comment: @StefanGehrig: please press F5.

Comment: I'm on a Mac - so no `F5` for me ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Simply use [`$_SESSION`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php)

Answer (score 1):

Solution with suitable example

```
<?php session_start();
$_SESSION['var1']='var 1 value';
$_SESSION['var2']='var 2 value';
$_SESSION['var3']='var 3 value';

$_SESSION['tmpvar1']='tmp var 1 value';
$_SESSION['tmpvar2']='tmp var 2 value';
$_SESSION['tmpvar3']='tmp var 3 value';

print_r($_SESSION);

foreach($_SESSION as $key=>$value)
{
    if(substr($key,0,3)=='tmp'){
        unset($_SESSION[$key]);
    }
}
print_r($_SESSION);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

If your are actually trying unset variables to do with a [session](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php)) you would loop through [`$_SESSION`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php).

If by `session variables` you mean "all variables declared in the scope of the current script" you would loop through [`$GLOBALS`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php) for all variables in the global scope, or the result of [`get_defined_vars()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-vars.php) for all variables in the current scope, e.g. the scope of the current function.

The code you have to actually do the loop and unset the variables is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Session itself is a big array, of arrays of arrays etc... so you need to make some recursive function which would search all the levels ($_SESSION["a"] can be an array whcih have some temps inside like $_SESSION["a"]["tmp_b"] ..)

So:

```
function resetTemps($arr)
{
    foreach( $arr as $key => $value )
    {
        if( is_array( $value ) )
        {
            resetTemps($value);
        }
        else
        {
            if( substr($key,0,3)=='tmp' )
            {
                unset( $arr[$key] );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then call it like

```
resetTemps($_SESSION);
```